# Bring a component on a JPanel to front (Java)

Tags: java, swing, focus, actionlistener

In VB, you can use `zOrder`.
In .Net, it's `.SetChildIndex`.

Before you ask, no I'm not using a layout manager in this case. If you have two components on top of each other, how do you change the order after they have already been displayed?

I have a button that slightly overlaps on top of another component (label), due to the lack of space. I added the JLabel to the form *before* the button, and when the form loads, it looks fine. However when the user clicks the button, the JLabel goes to the back, making a chunk of it disappear. Is there a way to keep it to the front? I have tried putting `label.grabFocus()` in the button's ActionListener but it did not work.

Comment: Sounds like a poor design to me. Mind posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so we can possibly suggest an alternate approach?

Comment: As a side note, if you are going to use Swing, you desperately need to learn how to use Layout Managers.

Comment: The use of repaint is a poor way to fix the problem.

Comment: I'll try to use layered panes and see what I get

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default Swing assumes components don't overlap so components can be repainted more efficiently. That is when you change a property on a component, only that component needs to be repainted.

When components overlap on the panel then you need to tell the panel so it can make sure all components are repainted in their proper ZOrder:

You do this by overriding the `isOptimizedDrawingEnabled()` method of the JPanel to return `false`.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel()
{
    @Override
    public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you set the "ZOrder"?

Comment: @CardinalSystem, By default the ZOrder is set automatically as you add a component to a panel. The ZOrder is increased as each component is added. Swing actually paints components in the reverse order they are added, so you could just change the order in which you add the components. Or you can manipulate the ZOrder after the fact by using the `Container.setComponentZOrder(...)` method

Answer (score 7):

you can also use the LayeredPane of your JFrame. With JFrame.getLayeredPane() you get a reference of the pane in use.

the add method of LayeredPane has up to 2 additional int parameters. the first specified the Layer of the component you'd add and the second contols the order inside this layer.

You can find more infos at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#layeredpane

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, this appears to be a poor design. Though `label.repaint()` works, its not the way you should do it. You are not specifying explicitly how these components overlap one on the other. For that a better approach would be Layered Panes. The java's counterpart for zOrder is Layered Pane. This link should help you: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html

just tell me if you have any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but would repaint work? bit of a hack if it does, maybe someone else could find a better way...

Comment: label.repaint() in the action listener works awesome. Didn't think of that. Thanks! Will accept soon.

Comment: See my answer. The API solution is to override the isOptimizedDrawingEnabled() method of the panel. Having the button ActionListener aware of components painted around it is not a very good solution.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't that obvious to make overlapping components behave in the right way. The most supported way is to use an OverlayLayout within your panel.

Comment: A LayeredPane is the most supported way.  An OverlayLayout is not even listed here:  http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: @jzd, You're right, but it's still a valid answer - [OverlayLayout Examples](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1401__OverlayLayout.htm)

Comment: @jzd All answers are valid actually, whether it's "good practice" or not. Actually in this case I wasn't looking for "best practice" or the "best way" to do it, but for the shortest answer that requires the smallest amount of effort possible to use.

Comment: Using an OverlayLayout is a valid answer.  My issue was describing it as the "Most supported way".

Comment: @David, learning the proper approach is better in the long run than a quick fix that uses the smallest effort.