# OverlayLayout doesn't respect the overlay order with focus change

Tags: java, swing, layout, overlay, visibility

I encountered a problem with `OverlayLayout`.

Basically, I created a component which allows to unroll an overlay content above a main content (like a drop down menu). It works!

The problem is: if I put a `JButton` on the main content (the content below), when I click on this button, then the button starts to appear above the overlay content !
I don't know why?

Does anyone know what the problem is ? Is it maybe the focus ?

Comment: probably it works on my pc without any issue, sure, unfortunatelly you can't to see that, isn't it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer!
It comes from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7012365/230513) on stackoverflow...

> When components overlap on the panel then you need to tell the panel so
>   it can make sure it repaints the components in their proper ZOrder:
>
> You do this by overriding the isOptimizedDrawingEnabled() method of
>   the JPanel to return false.