# How to create this button over the other button?

Tags: java, swing

As the title, I want to create two buttons in java swing and these two buttons can overlap each other (as image). I searched the internet but I could not find it.

[image]

Thanks so much

Comment: That's an odd requirement but if you _really_ want to do that you could try a custom layout manager (or even use absolute layout). Just add the buttons to the same container.

Comment: *"I searched the internet but I could not find it."* That's often a red flag that it's an illogical and counterintuitive thing to do, breaks the 'path of least surprise' for the end-user (a terrible thing to to to them) & that ultimately it **should *not* be done.**

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this by setting the `JFrame` layout to `Absolute Layout`, and adding a `JButton` on top of another `JButton`. Make sure the small button is on top of the other button in the navigator.

---

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the layered pane of `JFrame` like this:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;

public class ButtonOnTop
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JButton button1 = new JButton("jButton1");
    button1.setBounds(30, 50, 260, 160);

    JButton button2 = new JButton("jButton2");
    button2.setBounds(150, 150, 100, 40);

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLayeredPane layeredPane = f.getLayeredPane();
    layeredPane.add(button1, Integer.valueOf(0));
    layeredPane.add(button2, Integer.valueOf(1));

    f.setBounds(300, 200, 400, 300);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [OverlayLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/OverlayLayout.html) here.

An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (with comments inside) would be:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.OverlayLayout;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class OverlayLayoutExample extends JFrame {
    JPanel overlayoutPanel;
    JButton jButton2, jButton1;

    public OverlayLayoutExample() {

        overlayoutPanel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled() {
                //Required to have always visible both components
                return false;
            }
        };

        OverlayLayout overlay = new OverlayLayout(overlayoutPanel);
        overlayoutPanel.setLayout(overlay);
        jButton1 = new JButton("jButton");
        Dimension d1 = new Dimension(350, 100);
        jButton1.setMaximumSize(d1);
        jButton1.setAlignmentX(0.7f); //Some X-Y values, play with them
        jButton1.setAlignmentY(0.65f); //Some X-Y values, play with them

        jButton2 = new JButton("jButton2");
        Dimension d2 = new Dimension(100, 25);
        jButton2.setMaximumSize(d2);
        jButton2.setAlignmentX(0.01f); //Some X-Y values, play with them
        jButton2.setAlignmentY(0.01f); //Some X-Y values, play with them

        overlayoutPanel.add(jButton2); //First the top component
        overlayoutPanel.add(jButton1); //Then the above component

        getContentPane().add(overlayoutPanel);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 300);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new OverlayLayoutExample().setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

**More** about `isOptimizedDrawingEnabled()` can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010453/bring-a-component-on-a-jpanel-to-front-java/7012365#7012365)

Preview:

[image]